# Jenkinsfile - Null in environment section

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline

I have strange problem during build. This is my initial Jenkinsfiles:

```
pipeline {

    agent none

    environment {
        MAVEN_ARGS = "${HOST}"
    }

    stages {

        stage('Test step') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3-alpine'
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo "${HOST}"
                echo "${env.HOST}"
                echo "${MAVEN_ARGS}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why first two echos prints correct value of **HOST** variable and last echo prints **null**?

What is interesting when I delete stage agent section:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    environment {
        MAVEN_ARGS = "${HOST}"
    }

    stages {

        stage('Test step') {
            steps {
                echo "${HOST}"
                echo "${env.HOST}"
                echo "${MAVEN_ARGS}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every single echo is printing correctly **HOST** variable - this is obvious.

**Thanks for help :)**

Comment: Please have a look, you have `agent none` in first `Jenkinsfile` and `agent any` in second one, so you compare different things here.

Comment: Yes, you are right - lets focus on first code snippet :) "environment" variable MAVEN_ARGS  variable is not passed to docker container and jenkins environment variables are?